# Как в wordpress выключить кэширование css?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Прочитал море литературы как это сделать, перепробовал почти все но не хочет он выключать кэш.

Самое главное что с таким вот кодом, js скрипты не кэшируются а вот css файлы кэшируются, что делать? может кто скажет альтернативу или может я не так делаю что?

```
<link href="<?php bloginfo( 'template_directory' ); ?>/css/styles.css?<?php echo filemtime(TEMPLATEPATH . '/css/styles.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Можно при каждом переходе указать uniqid

Answer (score 2):

WordPress не содержит механизма кэширования файлов css. Вообще, никакого.

Кэширование производится сервером и браузером. Если не удается сбросить кэши через ctrl+f5 (что помогает в 99% случаев), то надо либо менять настройки apache/nginx на сервере, либо прибегнуть к тем советам, что даны в других ответах - посредством указания версии файла каждый раз сообщать браузеру, что появился "новый" файл css.

Answer (score 1):

Подключать стили нужно через [wp_enqueue_style](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style). Играя параметром `$ver` можно обновлять кеш. Напр по дате изменения файла.

Answer (score 1):

уникализируй используй код `style.css?<?php echo rand(1000,9999);?>`. Таким образом у тебя будет каждый раз "новый" файл

Answer (score 0):

код заработал, проблема оказалось в том что стили темы перекрывали стили шаблона, незнаю как но случайно вставил старый код шаблона в стили темы

Comment: Удаляйте вопрос тогда, как не имеющий никакого практического смысла для других пользователей.